# Cloud Data Storage across devices without Login (iCloud, CloudKit)

Tags: flutter, icloud, cloudkit

I do have a background as a native iOS software developer.
We had a couple of apps for iPhones and iPads that used CloudKit to sync data between the same App installed on different devices of a single user.

It was used for simple things like favorited items within apps that did not have any login or account mechanisms.

How would I achieve such a functionality in flutter?
Havent found any iCloud related plugins for dart/flutter.

Thank you!

Comment: Hey @Robin did you find a way to access CloudKit in flutter? There was this https://github.com/jaumecornado/DroidNubeKit for native Android which was not maintained and wonder if there's anything more up to date

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe there is a direct way to access the CloudKit from dart/flutter, however, there is nothing stopping you from trying this architecture.

Build a (PHP?)/CloudJS application on a webserver to serve REST-ful API calls that send/retrieve data from CloudKit Containers ([CloudKit Web Service Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitWebServicesReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015240-CH41-SW1)). You'll want to set up some server-to-server authentication for this to work.

Posting/Fetching data via the REST API calls from dart/flutter. There are many libs that facilitate this and author (BRIJESH) over on androidkt.com offers an interesting [walkthrough](https://androidkt.com/calling-rest-api-flutter-app/) of some options.

Comment: How do you like to authenticate/identify the iCloud user on your own webservice? I mean on iOS you can sync data without the need for a login. It just takes the iCloud storage container a user has by logging into iCloud on his iPhone. And that is the main reason why I'd like to use iCloud. If I have to bring my own authentication method I'd simply skip iCloud and use my own API :)

Comment: @RobinReiter This is new and I haven't used it yet but it is an option that might work - https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210318